# Calling a modal windows in a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got this script which works on a click of button, it pops up a modal window with a faded background. What i want to achieve this time is to include it in a conditional statement, the later part of my script is as below

```
 if (result != $version) { alert ('Your version is out of date') } } })
alert ('You are welcome back')
```

But i want to change the alert to a modal windows but can't find my way through

```
// JavaScript Document


$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $(".about").on("click", function () {
        // close button
        var closeBtn = $('<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete ui-shadow">Close</a>');

        // text you get from Ajax
        var content = "<p> hello folks, good evening</p>";

        // Popup body - set width is optional - append button and Ajax msg
        var popup = $("<div/>", {
            "data-role": "popup"
        }).css({
            width: $(window).width() / 0 + "px",
            padding: 5 + "px"
        }).append(closeBtn).append(content);

        // Append it to active page
        $.mobile.pageContainer.append(popup);

        // Create it and add listener to delete it once it's closed
        // open it
        $("[data-role=popup]").popup({
            dismissible: false,
            history: false,
            theme: "b",
            /* or a */
            positionTo: "window",
            overlayTheme: "b",
            /* "b" is recommended for overlay */
            transition: "pop",
            beforeposition: function () {
                $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")
                    .addClass("blur-filter");
            },
            afterclose: function () {
                $(this).remove();
                $(".blur-filter").removeClass("blur-filter");
            },
            afteropen: function () {
                /* do something */
            }
        }).popup("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: move the "open" call ( `$("[data-role=popup]").popup("open")` ) inside the if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to just trigger the click in the conditional:

```
if (result != $version) { 
    $(".about").trigger("click"); 
}
```

However, I'd refactor that click callback to a named function and be able to call it on both instances of the conditional and the button:

```
var openModal = function () {
        // close button
        var closeBtn = $('<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete ui-shadow">Close</a>');

        // text you get from Ajax
        var content = "<p> hello folks, good evening</p>";

        // Popup body - set width is optional - append button and Ajax msg
        var popup = $("<div/>", {
            "data-role": "popup"
        }).css({
            width: $(window).width() / 0 + "px",
            padding: 5 + "px"
        }).append(closeBtn).append(content);

        // Append it to active page
        $.mobile.pageContainer.append(popup);

        // Create it and add listener to delete it once it's closed
        // open it
        $("[data-role=popup]").popup({
            dismissible: false,
            history: false,
            theme: "b",
            /* or a */
            positionTo: "window",
            overlayTheme: "b",
            /* "b" is recommended for overlay */
            transition: "pop",
            beforeposition: function () {
                $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")
                    .addClass("blur-filter");
            },
            afterclose: function () {
                $(this).remove();
                $(".blur-filter").removeClass("blur-filter");
            },
            afteropen: function () {
                /* do something */
            }
        }).popup("open");
};


$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $(".about").on("click", openModal);
});
```

And in the conditional:

```
if (result != $version) { 
    openModal(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked, anyway is there a way possible instead of the text i have in the content variable, i could replace it with a div and call an external page inside the div

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing that. Can you create an additional question with more specifics and I'll take a look at it there?

Comment: i've created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671943/calling-an-external-page-into-a-modal-window-with-ajax