# Calling an external page into a modal window with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load an external page in a modal window. by default i've already added some text in the modal window, but i want to delete the text which says `"<p> hello folks, good evening</p>"` and instead call an external page into the modal window which contains a different message

```
var openModal = function () {
        // close button
        var closeBtn = $('<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete ui-shadow">Close</a>');

        // text you get from Ajax
        var content = "<p> hello folks, good evening</p>";

        // Popup body - set width is optional - append button and Ajax msg
        var popup = $("<div/>", {
            "data-role": "popup"
        }).css({
            width: $(window).width() / 0 + "px",
            padding: 5 + "px"
        }).append(closeBtn).append(content);

        // Append it to active page
        $.mobile.pageContainer.append(popup);

        // Create it and add listener to delete it once it's closed
        // open it
        $("[data-role=popup]").popup({
            dismissible: false,
            history: false,
            theme: "b",
            /* or a */
            positionTo: "window",
            overlayTheme: "b",
            /* "b" is recommended for overlay */
            transition: "pop",
            beforeposition: function () {
                $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")
                    .addClass("blur-filter");
            },
            afterclose: function () {
                $(this).remove();
                $(".blur-filter").removeClass("blur-filter");
            },
            afteropen: function () {
                /* do something */
            }
        }).popup("open");
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to load a page from an external website I would imagine it would be as simple as loading in an `iframe` and passing the URL to the site you want to load in. In your JQuery just change this line:

```
var content = "<p> hello folks, good evening</p>";
```

to

```
var content = "<iframe src='http://google.com' width='200' height='200'></iframe>";
```

Change the properties as needed. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your content var to equal `'<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="YOUR_URL" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>'`. For example, `'<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="http://jquery.com/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>'`

I added your code to a fiddle so you can try it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/4pjndrsc/1/

Hope that helps. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to load in the content from an external page rather than embedding an iframe, you can add the `$.ajax` call into your function:

```
var openModal = function () {
        // close button
        var closeBtn = $('<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete ui-shadow">Close</a>');


        // create the ajax call and create modal in the callback
        $.ajax({
            url: "content_page.html",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                // text you get from Ajax
                var content = response;


                // Popup body - set width is optional - append button and Ajax msg
                var popup = $("<div/>", {
                    "data-role": "popup"
                }).css({
                    width: $(window).width() / 0 + "px",
                    padding: 5 + "px"
                }).append(closeBtn).append(content);

                // Append it to active page
                $.mobile.pageContainer.append(popup);

                // Create it and add listener to delete it once it's closed
                // open it
                $("[data-role=popup]").popup({
                    dismissible: false,
                    history: false,
                    theme: "b",
                    /* or a */
                    positionTo: "window",
                    overlayTheme: "b",
                    /* "b" is recommended for overlay */
                    transition: "pop",
                    beforeposition: function () {
                        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")
                            .addClass("blur-filter");
                    },
                    afterclose: function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                        $(".blur-filter").removeClass("blur-filter");
                    },
                    afteropen: function () {
                        /* do something */
                    }
                }).popup("open");
            },
            error: function () {
                //handle error here
            } 


          });

};
```